# How to prevent too aggressive text elide in QTableview?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I have an issue with text elide in Qt being too aggressive in a table, see picture.
[image]

The cell with the full figure 0.8888.... I've edited since the QTableWidget was shown, the others are are as the were when the QTableWidget was created. It seems like the elide is calculated on a lesser width that is actually the case. How can I prevent this and get proper text elide immediately when the widget becomes visible?

Simplifide code to reproduce:

```
QTableWidget *tableWidget;
tableWidget = new QTableWidget(Dialog);
tableWidget->setGeometry(QRect(40, 20, 256, 192));
tableWidget->setRowCount(4);
tableWidget->setColumnCount(1);
tableWidget->setItem(0, 0, new QTableWidgetItem("0.234823489789234"));
```

and result

[image]

Note that I would like to avoid doing the elide myself since the user can edit the value. Doing the elide myself would then mean putting back the real value when editing starts, perhaps via delegates. Would be complicated.

Comment: Prepare a code example.

Comment: @user6528273 Done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### When everything just worked...

...the solution could have been as simple as disabling the elide in the `QTableWidget` and set directly an elided string as item's text like that:

```
tableWidget->setTextElideMode(Qt::ElideNone);
tableWidget->setItem(0, 0, new QTableWidgetItem(tableWidget->fontMetrics().elidedText("0.234823489789234", Qt::ElideRight, tableWidget->columnWidth(0))));
```

Unfortunately, `QTableWidget` (or maybe it is `QStyledItemDelegate`) does not respect the `QAbstractItemView::textElideMode` property.

Thus, you need to do it the hard way, i.e. using delegates. Do not worry though, it is not much more complicated.

### Solution

1. Subclass [`QStyledItemDelegate`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html) and reimplement its `paint` method like this:

   ```
    void Delegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                         const QModelIndex &index) const
    {
        if (!index.isValid())
            return;

        QStyleOptionViewItem opt = option;
        initStyleOption(&opt, index);
        int padding = 3;

        painter->save();
        painter->setClipRect(opt.rect);
        opt.rect = opt.rect.adjusted(padding, padding, -padding, -padding);
        painter->drawText(opt.rect, Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignVCenter,
                          opt.fontMetrics.elidedText(opt.text, Qt::ElideRight,
                                                     opt.rect.width()));
        painter->restore();

        opt.rect = option.rect;
        opt.textElideMode = Qt::ElideNone;
        opt.text = "";

        QApplication::style()->drawControl(QStyle::CE_ItemViewItem, &opt, painter);
    }
   ```

Feel free to change the padding to a suitable value.

2. Set the `tableWidget`'s delegate for the desired column like this:

   ```
    tableWidget->setItemDelegateForColumn(0, new Delegate(this));
   ```

where `Delegate` is your `QStyledItemDelegate` subclass.

### Result

The result of this modification is a column with a properly elided text.

[image: Table with a properly elided text]

Comment: Thanks. Should one post a Qt improvement request somewhere? I feel that this is a standard situation the framework should solve.

Comment: @user2052153, good idea. You can report a Qt bug [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/secure/Dashboard.jspa).

Comment: I discovered that this solution won't respect colors returned by the QAbstractTableModel::data(). What would be the best way to fix that? Let the elide have a pointer to the model and ask the model? I couldn't find the foreground color in QStyleOptionViewItem

Comment: @user2052153, You can get the same data as `QAbstractTableModel::data()` with [`QModelIndex::data`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html#data). Then you cau use the painter to paint what you need. If you need detailed instructions of how to achieve this, please ask another question, referencing this one and describing exactly what should be painted, and I would be glad to provide an answer.

Comment: Thanks, but not needed. Very convenient way to get the color data. I only had to add 
painter->setPen(index.data(Qt::ForegroundRole).value<QColor>());

Comment: _`painter->setPen(index.data(Qt::ForegroundRole).value<QColor>());`_ Yep! That is exactly it. Additionally you might also make it respect the background role like this: `painter->fillRect(option.rect, index.data(Qt::BackgroundRole).value<QColor>());`

Comment: The much simpler answer given by other users to this question worked for me: `tableWidget->setWordWrap(false);`

Comment: @Hitman, that's great! That means, you might consider upvoting the answer.

Comment: 3 years later, this is still not fixed apparently ?

Answer (score 3):

I think the solution is just:

```
tableWidget->setWordWrap(false);
```

If you increase the row height, you'll probably find that the text (well, number) has been "word-wrapped" at the decimal point.

I figured this out while finding the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73322362/strange-behavior-of-qtableview-with-text-containing-slashes).