# Proper elide and peridically set background color of QTableView cell and possible for user to edit value

Tags: qt, qtableview, qabstractitemmodel

To summarize:
I need a solution for QTableView cells which fulfills

1. Proper elide
2. Possible to set background color by emitting dataChanged() from the model in a method called by a timer at ~50ms
3. Possible for user to edit value as normal.

QTBUG for the elide: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-87178

Solution which fulfills req 1 but not 2 and 3: [How to prevent too aggressive text elide in QTableview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64198197/how-to-prevent-too-aggressive-text-elide-in-qtableview)

Sample program which demonstrates the issue:https://udokaelectronics.com/files/untitled.zip

Comment out
`ui->tableView->setItemDelegate(elideDelegate);`
to see behavior with and without elide delegate.

Anyone with ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've come up with.

1. A delegate for keeping track of when an edit is in progress. Then use the state of the delegate in the table models to avoid emitting dataChanged()

```
#pragma once

#include <QStyledItemDelegate>

class EditInProgressDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
 public:
    EditInProgressDelegate(QObject* parent = nullptr) : QStyledItemDelegate(parent), editInProgress_(false){};

    QWidget* createEditor(QWidget* parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const override;
    void destroyEditor(QWidget* editor, const QModelIndex& index) const override;

    bool editInProgress() const { return editInProgress_; }
    int editInProgressRow() const { return editInProgressRow_; }
    int editInProgressColumn() const { return editInProgressColumn_; }

 protected:
    mutable bool editInProgress_;
    mutable int editInProgressRow_;
    mutable int editInProgressColumn_;
};
```

```
#include "EditInProgressDelegate.h"

QWidget* EditInProgressDelegate::createEditor(QWidget* parent,
                                              const QStyleOptionViewItem& option,
                                              const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    editInProgress_ = true;
    editInProgressColumn_ = index.column();
    editInProgressRow_ = index.row();
    return QStyledItemDelegate::createEditor(parent, option, index);
};

void EditInProgressDelegate::destroyEditor(QWidget* editor, const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    editInProgress_ = false;
    QStyledItemDelegate::destroyEditor(editor, index);
}
```

2. A second delegate with a magic 10 to handle elide

```
#pragma once

#include "EditInProgressDelegate.h"

// This entire class is a plaster because QTableWidgetItem or
// QStyledItemDelegate malfunctions, see
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64198197/how-to-prevent-too-aggressive-text-elide-in-qtableview
// and
// https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-87178
class ElideDelegate : public EditInProgressDelegate
{
 public:
    ElideDelegate(QObject* parent = nullptr) : EditInProgressDelegate(parent){};

    void paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const override;
};
```

```
#include "ElideDelegate.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <QPainter>

void ElideDelegate::paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
    {
        return;
    }

    QStyleOptionViewItem opt = option;
    initStyleOption(&opt, index);

    opt.text = opt.fontMetrics.elidedText(opt.text,
                                          Qt::ElideRight,
                                          opt.rect.width() - 10);  // 10 was determined by experimentation
    opt.textElideMode = Qt::ElideNone;
    QApplication::style()->drawControl(QStyle::CE_ItemViewItem, &opt, painter);
}
```